# TextField: Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, textfield

I have a form view designed to edit data for an existing item and I'm able to display the Binded (bound?) value without a problem. The TextField gives me an error of "Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred"

Here's the file where the problem is occurring.

```
import SwiftUI


struct EditMeasurementView: View {

    @Binding var measurementItem: MeasurementItem

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("\(measurementItem.weight)")
            TextField("Weight", text: $measurementItem.weight)
            // TextField("Date", text: $measurementItem.mdate)
        }
    }
}

struct EditMeasurementView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EditMeasurementView(measurementItem:  .constant(MeasurementItem(weight:"99",mdate:"1/1/2001")))
    }
}
```

The first item in the form is fine and if I click on '$measurementItem' is is bound to the @Binding. The second item is where the error appears and if I click on '$measurementItem' there, it does not indicate is is linked back to the @Binding.

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the code given. It compile fine as long as I create a trivial MeasurementItem struct with two String properties. Can you post a version of this that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @RobNapier I edited my post with a dropbox link for the whole project. Probably something dumb but I'm brand new to development and trying to teach myself...

Comment: The whole project is way too much. Create a small test project. Copy over things until it problem appears. That will show you where it is. It should only take a few dozen lines at most; probably much less.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code to duplicate the problem described above:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MeasurementItem {
    let weight: String
    let mdate: String
}

struct EditMeasurementView: View {
    @State var measurementItem: MeasurementItem

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("\(measurementItem.weight)")
            TextField("Weight", text: $measurementItem.weight)
        }
    }
}

struct EditMeasurementView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EditMeasurementView(measurementItem:  MeasurementItem(weight:"99",mdate:"1/1/2001"))
    }
}
```

The line `TextField("Weight", text: $measurementItem.weight)` will generate the error described by the OP.

However the real problem is not with `TextField("Weight", text: $measurementItem.weight)` itself but that `$measurementItem.weight` is a constant (i.e it is declared with `let` instead of `var`) and because it's a constant the `TextField` cannot change the value of `$measurementItem.weight` .